# How to frame a screenshot in Android Studio with an Android Wear device?

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I select a different device besides just "Generic Phone" or "Generic Tablet" in Android Studio to frame a taken screenshot? I'm interested in an Android Wear frame but I can't select it from the dropdown as the option doesn't appear.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use this [gradle plugin](https://github.com/chemouna/frame-gradle-plugin) to automate this  and with gradle extension give the path for the folder containing the screenshots (check the sample in the project).

Disclaimer: I'm the author of that plugin.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.